# Nginx with FastCGI returns emty page

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I am trying to do some authentication on url of file served by nginx through FastCGI to either grant access or not to the file this is my location:

```
location / {
    root   /var/www/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /etc/nginx/conf.d/process_request.php;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

and the process_request.php only echos a parameter(This should originaly parse some parameters and do some processing and either returns 200 OK or 403 Forbidden and based on the response nginx should either show the file or not ):

```
<?php echo "test"; ?>
```

what i understand is that the fastCGI returns to nginx to serve the file,but what I get is a blank page with http response 200.  what am I missing ?

Comment: Do you have error_reporting on? Looks like you're missing a `;` after `"test"`

Comment: Yeah I have it on, Nope that was only missing when i copied the code. I 've updated the code